# Image a Windows PC using Linux

Tags: linux, clone, imaging, ghost, clonezilla

I want to create a bootable USB disk (like Clonezilla) and create images which are saved as GHO/GHS

I also want to restore images back to the PC and do the following tasks (if possible)

1. Rename the computer using our normal conventions
2. Join the Domain

I'd prefer a Linux solution but I am open to other systems.

Comment: The imaging software should just plop the image down on the disk.  Numbers 1 & 2 should be handled via `sysprep` and its unattend.xml config.

Comment: our bootable flash drives used to be Grub.  That was the only piece that was linux.  Are you talking about a Linux-based deployment server?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use a Linux solution to image/deploy Windows systems? Nothing wrong with it, but there are plenty of tools (like Acronis) that are geared toward Windows deployments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are deploying Windows. Your tasks can be baked into any image (See [Sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766514%28WS.10%29.aspx)). Anything that can deploy an image should do the trick after that.

Alternatively, (and here is my MS plug for the day), if you have a 2008 R2 server setup -- consider using [MDT2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791). It's quite easy to setup and can easily handle your pre/post install steps. It's included for "free" with your server license. It will provide you with a central management point for your images but still allow deployment from [removable media](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2011/09/02/getting-more-into-dvd-media-based-deployment.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure CloneZilla can do that.
Read the documentation. I did it onde with a verry small script or couple of reponse file that you need to put on a server... Probably TFTP with NFS.

Answer (score 0):

[FOG](http://fogproject.org) is a reasonably full-featured imaging & deployment solution (host renaming, domain joining, software deployment, printer management etc.). Uses TFTP & NFS, mostly written in PHP, uses pxelinux & partimage to do the actual imaging.

I imagine it *should* be possible to install it to a persistent Live USB Linux distro, but I'm not sure where you'd get enough storage space for your images unless you have a NFS server somewhere.

Comment: Our USB drives are fairly large. We have 32GB sticks. Most of our GHO files are between 2GB to 6GB

Comment: Can it create GHO/GHS files?